# Where can I find the file history window in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

Where can I find the file history window in Windows 7?

Comment: Is PC Settings -> Update and Recovery -> File History what you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

@TimWilliams your answer applies to Windows 8/8.1 not Windows 7.

For Windows 7:

**Control Panel> System and Security> Backup and Restore**

You can also click **Start,** type *backup*, and select **Backup and Restore.**

You should see something like this if you haven't previously set up backup:
[image]

Or something like this if you have already set up backup:
[image]